# Composite Index Design (Narrow vs Wide) when searching on date range

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing, query-optimization

I have an argument with my colleague regarding the design of the composite index. If two fields are being used in the query, I reckon the more unique field should be first.

Look at this example

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblPurchase](
    [PurchaseId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ProductId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ItemId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [PurchaseDate] [date] NOT NULL,
    [CurrencyId] [int] NOT NULL,
    ...
    ...
    ...
CONSTRAINT [PK_tblPurchase] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [PurchaseId] ASC,
    [ProductId] ASC,
    [ItemId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

At the moment we have 2 currencies and we have about 2 million records (note: we may add 2 new currencies in near future).

I decided to create an index using `[PurchaseDate]-[CurrencyId]` as the composite index, but my colleague argue that we should flip it to use `[CurrencyId]-[PurchaseDate]` as CurrencyId is less unique. Our query is:

```
SELECT *
FROM [tblPurchase]
WHERE [PurchaseDate] >= '2022-01-01' AND [PurchaseDate] <= '2022-06-01' AND [CurrencyId] = 1
```

Any thought?

Comment: I mean the first field should narrow the result more. We run it and to my surprise, the execution time is nearly the same... That is why my argument (that the field that narrows the result more should be used as the first field) doesn't hold up :(

Comment: You're right, @Sam, more selective field should go first to narrow down results for second condition check.

Comment: your colleague is right but for the wrong reason

Comment: @Limonka Selectivity only really applies to equality predicates, not inequality predicates nor join, grouping and sorting columns. So it's a bit of misunderstanding

Comment: Always happy to learn, @Charlieface

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The optimal index for

```
WHERE PurchaseDate >= '2022-01-01' AND PurchaseDate <= '2022-06-01' AND CurrencyId = 1
```

is `[CurrencyId]-[PurchaseDate]`

this has nothing to do with selectivity.

It can use the first column to do an equality seek on `CurrencyId` and then a range seek on the second column so read exactly the right rows to resolve the query.

With the reverse index order the best that it can do is a range seek on the date predicate and then a residual predicate to discard the rows read for other currencies. So the index seek will read more rows in this case (assuming that other currency ids exist in the date range than just `1`).

To use the phone book analogy (ordered by lastname, firstname) this is in the same way as it would be straight forward to find all *Smiths* with first name from *Alice* to *Bob* (find the point where Alice Smith starts/would be and just read all entries until find the first one ordered after "Bob Smith")

but it is much more work to use it to find all *Alices* with surname from *Clark* to *Davis* (SQL Server would read all the entries from Clark to Davis and discard the non Alice ones)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I understand a bit more about indexing. Just curious, if there is only 1 CurrencyId, is it still ok to use [CurrencyId]-[PurchaseDate]?

Comment: If you only have CurrencyId of `1` then both will read exactly the same number of rows so for this specific query it won't make much difference which you choose. You may prefer `PurchaseDate, CurrencyId` if you have other queries not shown which would benefit from having that as the first column in the index. e.g. just `WHERE [PurchaseDate] BETWEEN X AND Y` or `TOP 10 ... ORDER BY [PurchaseDate] `

Comment: Hi @Martin, just one more question, is it fair to say that the most important order (when designing an index) is `equality - narrower selective field - range search`

Comment: @Sam - the issue of selectivity is generally *way* over stated. When adding a composite index to support a query if there are multiple possible orderings all equally suitable I'd look at other queries with seekable predicates against those columns and choose the most suitable one to help those (taking into account how frequently each of those queries are executed) - Selectivity is only important in that if the index is non covering and the first column(s) in the index are not very selective the index might not be used as expected lookups would be more expensive than just scanning the table.

Comment: Hi @Martin, if I have [UserId] which is optional in the search/filter, should I stick [UserId] at the end `[CurrencyId]-[PurchaseDate]-[UserId]`? Or should I create 2 separate indexes `[CurrencyId]-[PurchaseDate]` AND `[CurrencyId]-[UserId]-[PurchaseDate]`? The total number of records are about 60 - 100 millions. Here is the other post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73780266/create-multiple-indexes-vs-1-index-multiple-columns-with-range-column-not-at-t?noredirect=1#comment130281346_73780266