# Create multiple indexes vs 1 index (multiple columns) with range column not at the end

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have multiple columns which I need to index. However, `UserId` is an optional search and `DateOrdered` is **not** optional.

Here (a simplified version) of the select statement

```
SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[tblOrder]
WHERE ([ProductId] = @ProductId) AND ([ItemSizeId] = @ItemSizeId) AND
      ([DateOrdered] >= @StartDate) AND ([DateOrdered] <= @EndDate) --(optionally AND [UserId] = @UserId)
```

I am thinking of creating composite index of `ProductId_ItemSizeId_DateOrdered_UserId`. Alternatively, I can create 2 composite indexes of `ProductId_ItemSizeId_DateOrdered` and `ProductId_ItemSizeId_UserId_DateOrdered`

The order records are up to 20 million orders per month. Which approach is better?

Thanks.

Comment: "It depends". How many different queries do you have hitting the table? What is the choke point on the queries? What does you query plan state? And probably more importantly, what is the part of the query that cuts down the table the most? If the date ordered are the most limiting part of the query, it might make more sense to put date first, and then product ID, and then item size. If Item size is the more limiting part of the table, it might make sense to use that first. More would need to be known about the table before answering the question.

Comment: Do you really need `select *` in the query? Even if you have covering indexes for the columns in the `where` clause it's going to have to do a second lot of index seeks or row lookups to return all of the other columns in the table. i.e.: A reduced set of selected columns could be included in the `include` portion of the index(es) to avoid the second hit.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning yes, It is just a simplified example. I did not use `SELECT *`. @RobertShannon, from what I learned from the previous post, range seek is bad. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72474123/composite-index-design-narrow-vs-wide-when-searching-on-date-range/72474408?noredirect=1#comment128070225_72474408

Comment: @Sam why not experiment a little and use something like sp_blitz with just the one index and after uptime, see if there are issues that could be resolved adding a different index? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5QAL9itupMA